# Αre there bathrooms on the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

I know that it's a weird question, but I haven't seen a single bathroom on the Enterprise, not even on blueprints.

Do they exist?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops

Comment: The uniforms function as dune-style [Stillsuits](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Stillsuit), jk.  "Urine and feces are processed in the thigh pads."

Comment: If by bathroom, you mean shower, sink, toilet combinations, they would just be considered part of a crew cabin. If by just toilet sink,  you need to use the navy term *head*

Comment: If you're not willing to accept the comment/answer from @calccrypto, then this question could be asked of almost any SF/F franchise. Does the *Millenium Falcon* have a bathroom? Does Bag End? What about the TARDIS? Or the *Nebuchadnezzar*?

Comment: Babylon 5 often showed the bathrooms, even having scenes taking place in communal bathrooms (stay out of the methane-breathers bathrooms!).

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bathroom

Comment: No, urine and faeces is regularly teleported out of the bladder and digestive tract to an appropriate disposal location.

Comment: Do you mean "Αre there **toilets**"?

Comment: The Franz Joseph blueprints of the original NCC-1701 showed toilets.

Comment: Here's the answer you're looking for: http://www.spaceavalanche.com/2009/03/16/next-generation/

Comment: @IQAndreas "Picard to transporter room 6, beam the contents of my bowels to 100,000 kilometers off the starboard bow, on the double!"

Comment: @IQAndreas If some sort of diplomatic engagement has concluded unsatisfacorily, I have just thought of a wonderful way to follow up.

Comment: The Turbo lift. You get there while you go there.

Comment: *Which* Enterprise? The [blueprints of the Enterprise-D (TNG)](http://www.amazon.com/BLUEPRINTS-STAR-GENERATION-NCC-1701-D-Generation/dp/0671500937/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1423310233&sr=8-1&keywords=trek+blueprints) do feature structures that could be interpreted as bathrooms.

Comment: There's certainly a swimming pool in the TARDIS. Let's just hope the Doctor doesn't...

Comment: There certainly should be at least one toilet--we see numerous references to the Captain's Log. :)

Comment: "Don't you people from the 24th century ever pee?" - That genius who invented warp drive...

Comment: One of Jimmy Doohan's go-to jokes for his con appearances addressed this very subject. "We set our phasers on 'disintegrate'...and aimed VERY carefully"

Answer (score 38):

Yes, of course there are.

The need to excrete waste matter was not genetically engineered out of humans (and other Federation member species) by the 23rd century.

There are next to no explicit references in the shows, though the Enterprise-D has a door labelled "HEAD" on the Bridge, and there were verbal references in Voyager to such rooms.

[image: The Head on the USS Enterprise-D Bridge]

In DS9, Bashir stated that it was "best not to think too much" about how waste extraction worked. Rom worked on the station's waste extraction facilities more than once.

Comment: It wasn't genetically engineered out, but they DO have transporters.

Comment: @Plutor Hah good point

Comment: You can find them: http://www.pixeltrek.com/

Comment: There's a door to the head *on the bridge*? I'm sure there's a "Number One" joke in here somewhere...

Comment: @Plutor - Mr O'Brien, its that time again. - Yes sir, activating now. - Mr O'Brien, you appear to have removed my entire small intestine. - Sorry sir, won't happen again. - I should hope not Mr aargh *dies*.

Comment: You answered regarding toilets, but what about actual Bath Rooms.  That is, rooms with baths in them?

Comment: @Tim: A bathroom need not have a bath in it, at least not where I come from. Anyway, IIRC we see a bath in mimetic-B'Elanna's mimetic-quarters in _Course: Oblivion_. It stands to reason that all officers (or, at least, senior officers) have full bathrooms attached to their quarters.

Comment: The "best not to think too much" line was addressed to the audience.

Comment: @imallett: No it wasn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - You're assuming U.S. english, where "bathroom" means a toilet.  Everywhere else, it's not a bathroom unless there's an actual bath.  My point is that you need to think internationally in your responses.

Comment: @Tim: Assuming US English? I am English. I despise people assuming US English. Maybe it's different in your neck of the woods, but up here in Nottingham, "bathroom" is perfectly idiomatic! Not that I wasn't enjoying your unsolicited bollocking....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (out of universe)

Comment: Another explicit reference is made in Season 1 of TNG in the Episode "Home Soil" when the life form on a planet which was being terraformed interfaces with the Enterprise computer.

An Engineering Crewmember states, "The quarantine seal is getting weaker. Every time I try to redirect backup it goes somewhere else. I think I've. No, it's locked three people in a turbolift and two more in the programmers' rest room."

Comment: @imallett: Out of universe, every line on the show is addressed to the audience :P

Comment: @Bamboo: I read that as literally a room for rest. Why would programmers' have their own WC? Then again, why would they have their own room for rest, I suppose.

Comment: Which episode was it when Bashir said that?

Answer (score 22):

Memory alpha mentions a toilet in the Star Trek brig (prison cell):

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Brig

especially in Star Trek V: The Final Frontier.

[image]

There is a whole separate [toilet](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Toilet) entry in Memory Alpha however the toilet in the brig in Star Trek V remains as far as I know, the only visible representation of a potty on the series.

Comment: @Roboken:   The shallowness of this disturbs me.  It looks like it's asking for a look of accidental contact of, uh, parts and, uh stuff.  And splashback.     Unless this makes novel use of force field, gravity, transporter, or phaser technology.

Comment: Frictionless surfaces, maybe?

Comment: Vacuum pumps. :-)

Comment: It's a brig, not supposed to be neat or comfortable

Comment: @cde - if you look at toilets in contemporary American prisons (known globally for their comfort and cleanliness) you will see that their toilets have much more depth allowing less contact of 'parts' -- even if they lack toilet seats and toilet covers. :-)

Comment: @robo mostly due to toilet technology. Basic gravity toilets requirements require that head room.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Perhaps they use a tractor beam.

Comment: @ThePopMachine And even if it did... use... any of those things, I might be a little... afraid... to use it.

Comment: This begs the question -- in the 24th century, do men stand up to pee or sit down? And where is the toilet paper dispenser?

Comment: @RoboKaren:  They don't have paper.   They must use a PADD.

Comment: @RoboKaren There are these three seashells...

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I'd never take a PADD from Riker, just for that reason alone.

Answer (score 14):

William Riker shows us exactly where the *only* bathroom on the Enterprise was in the 1994 documentary "Journey's End: The Saga of *Star Trek — The Next Generation*."

Comment: I **strongly** suspect he was being facetious but still a good find.

Comment: @Richard: Don't you mean.... fecesious? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - This is the only time I'll let someone get away with a crap answer (badoom - tish!)

Comment: @Richard: You're just taking the piss now

Comment: @Richard You guys are just flush with jokes this weekend, aren't you?

Comment: "There's a very thin line between a remotely funny pun and a painfully cringy one." - President Laira Rillak of the UFP

Answer (score 8):

This was addressed in my favourite Star Trek: Enterprise episode, Breaking The Ice.

The chief engineer of the Enterprise is asked by some Earth schoolchildren how the toilets on the Enterprise work. He tells them that all biological waste on the ship is recycled into other materials and used to make items such as replacement uniform boots.

Comment: This, however, only relates to a single vessel.

Comment: That's true. The discovery of replicator technology in later centuries would certainly change the way they make new boots. I suppose they might feed waste matter from the loo into the replicator to recycle it.

Comment: Actually, they don't ([for the most part](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126619/20774))

Answer (score 8):

Of course Starships have toilets, and blueprints explicitly show and detail them.

### U.S.S. Enterprise NCC-1701-D

The [blueprints](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/star-trek-the-next-generation-enterprise.php) from Rick Sternback display toilets on various decks, here is a sample of Decks 1 (the Bridge) and 2. You can see a "head" on Deck 1, and on the Officers' quarters on Deck 2.

[image]

### Enterprise NX-01

The Enterprise NX-01 [blueprints](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/enterprise-nx-01-deckplans.php) also show toilets, i.e. the room labeled as 18 on Deck A:

[image]

### Miranda Class

The blueprints of the Miranda Class also show "heads" on various decks:

[image]
[image]

---

*These are just some examples. More blueprints can be seen at [Cygnus X-1](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints-main2.php).*

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Frakes hosted a *Star Trek* top 10 shows at the end of *ST:TNG*, and said that the *Enterprise* had only one bathroom - and he pointed to a schematic screen of the ship, and to the room.

He wasn't joking.  That was the only bathroom identified on the ship.  I don't recall if it was the bridge area or not.

Comment: Another answer (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81086/%CE%91re-there-bathrooms-on-the-enterprise/81110#81110) already has a link to that spot in a youtube copy of it.

Comment: Agree. Going to flag it as a dupe