# Where does the second door in Captain Janeway's 'Ready Room' lead?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the episode Voy: Repression, I noticed that when Captain Janeway is escorted into the Ready Room to be executed by Tuvok, she comes through a second door.

**Where does the second exit in the Ready Room lead?**

Comment: We see in the episode *Shattered* that the second door from Janeway's ready room leads to a corridor. More than likely it connects to the briefing room, and I'm pretty sure that there is a cargo bay somewhere behind the bridge too, but not sure if that is mentioned at some point or why I'm believing that.

Comment: Possibly related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81086/44480

Comment: You see them leave the briefing room through the second exit when they are dismissed sometimes it's unlikely they go through the captains ready room back to the bridge

Comment: Although not at all canon, the defunct company Strategic Design had done up blueprints for the Intrepid class star ship. Decks 1 - 3 are laid out [here](http://i.imgur.com/zqCMVPh.jpg). As you can see these are not completely accurate when compared to Richard's answer below.

Comment: Obvious, un-evidenced guess: wherever else it goes, that door also allows access to the Captain's toilet. The amount of coffee Janeway drinks she's going to need one. (TNG technical manual says there's one off the captain's ready room on Galaxy-class starships, around the corner from the replicator)

Comment: @xantec - I looked at those. They seem to have made assumptions based on the blueprints for the galaxy class ships

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It seems to lead through a small ante-chamber back out into the corridor that runs behind the bridge.

**Voy: Shattered**
[image]

Presumably there will be times when you want a crewman to attend the Captain in the Ready Room but without them having to go through the Bridge first.

---

You can also see the (unlabelled) exit in the original set plans, sold in the "[It's a wrap](https://www.flickr.com/photos/99878876@N02/13960542098/in/album-72157644597012434/)" prop auction.

[image]

Comment: Or alternatively, the captain may want to go somewhere without having to go through the bridge, or to dismiss a crewman without forcing them through the bridge. A variety of usages.

Comment: There are situations where someone has to see the captain, or is ordered to see the captain, with that person having absolutely no business *being* on the bridge.

Comment: @devsolar - Exactly so. They might be a security hazard or just not have bridge clearance for some reason. If they're upset (after being disciplined) you might not want them go through the bridge. Also, having a room with a single exit seems quite risky in itself.

Comment: Could someone highlight where the exit is?  Red,  free hand circle preferably. I'm honestly struggling to see it.

Answer (score 3):

I have to disagree with [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121622/31394).

From the schematics of Intrepid class ships, available e.g. [here](http://oehler1990.bplaced.net/blueprints/intrepid_original/sd-intrepid-nx-74600-sheet-9-x.jpg) we get a different picture. Here's a blowup of Deck 1:

[image]

The other door in the ready room leads into what looks like a personal head / shower room, which I believe makes more sense than an exit to a hallway. At any rate, there's no access from there to the turbolift, it seems.

You can also have a look at [this version](http://pre10.deviantart.net/3c73/th/pre/f/2014/018/d/9/uss_odyssey___deck_1_layout_by_sumghai-d72sb4x.png) of the Intrepid-class schematics for the U.S.S. Odyssey.

Comment: These schematics were produced by a company called Strategic Design and are non-canon, as they contradict what is shown in the show (see the GIF in Richard's answer).

Comment: These images are fan-fic.

Comment: @Richard: Before I delete this answer - I find it somewhat unreasonable that fans would go to a lot of trouble to create incorrect schematics of deck 1, to the level of contradicting canon. Adding to canon, sure, but, well... I dunno.

Comment: @einpoklum - These sorts of schematics are quite useful for fans planning out RPGs. When they conflict with later episodes, it's annoying for all concerned.