# Did the Enterprise have public/common restrooms?

Tags: star-trek

The question is pretty straight forward. I can't imagine everybody goes back to their quarters to take a leak every time.

Comment: Non canon, non legends, non serious answer. But [really relevant](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_of7mShM5N1g/SwX2rzEFpzI/AAAAAAAAAZk/uh6e3k98fTI/s1600/mad_sttmp_02.jpg)

Comment: given the way transporter technology exists the provide food everywhere, they probably use similar technology for waste disposal. Similar to the way they showed it in Asimov (where toilet bowls found in archeological digs could not be identified).

Comment: @Machavity - Hmm. Makes me wonder who needed the steps in front of the urinal...

Comment: Also non serious but [really relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP1lN50OGlE)

Comment: If I recall correctly the public bathroom scene in Babylon 5's _Signs and Portents_ was partially staged as a dig at the pristine bathroom-less Star Trek universe...

Comment: @sabbahillel: This makes me picture Picard trying to plant his butt in the replicator of his ready room when he has to go number 2 while on duty.

Comment: specifically, [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81087/5184) mentions one that is in a common area.