# Are there bathrooms on Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Inspired by this recently [resurrected question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81086/%CE%91re-there-bathrooms-on-the-enterprise) and beginning a re-watch of ST:Voyager.

Comment: By bathroom, do you mean a literal room with a bath or a room with a toilet and sink?

Comment: An actual bathroom, not just a lavatory or powder room. ^_^

Comment: No.  That's why they were so eager to get back to Earth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Janeway's [stateroom](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quarters) has a tub.

[image]

Whereas the average crew quarters seem to only have a sonic shower.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there are!

In the first episode of *Voyager* (the Caretaker), [Tuvok walks in on Neelix taking a bath](https://youtu.be/IDPHW21R13E). This happens in guest quarters (not a holodeck), so regular crew quarters may not have bathtubs.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Neelix mentions latrines in "Bride of Chaotica."  He tells Janeaway "Replicators aren't the only systems of convenience offline. We've only got four functioning lavatories for a ship of a hundred and fifty people."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Neexlix aand Capt. Janeway use a bath, Torres has a sonic shower on more than one occasion.

Neelix also mentions the fact that voyager has latrines, as some were broken... but I can't find specific reference to the episode. The only written source i've found is :-
http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Why_does_it_seem_that_there_are_no_bathrooms_on_Star_Trek

I *think* the episode is Year of Hell.