# Has Picard ever said "I have to go, Number One"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Has Jean Luc Picard ever said, "I have to go, Number One (or two)".?

Comment: “I think I can withstand the dvs”. That’s what they all think. To begin with.

Comment: Think of all the rep getting flushed away

Comment: @Valorum - that joke was bad, and you should feel bad.  In fact, I'd say that joke was just crappy.

Comment: @Jeff - I work very hard on my jokes. In fact, you could say that I toil et it.

Comment: Where would they go #1 or #2? There aren't any bathrooms on the bridge (or anywhere on the Enterprise, are there?). :-)

Comment: @RobertF - [Αre there bathrooms on the Enterprise?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81086/%CE%91re-there-bathrooms-on-the-enterprise)

Comment: @RobertF - Maybe there's a reason that all the versions of the Starfleet uniform have black pants (or very short skirts). :-)

Comment: I hate to be the wet blanket, but why would you even ask about Number 2? Unless you have no knowledge of the show, it's kind of obvious that nobody has that title on the D.

Comment: OMG, are we down to D jokes now.

Comment: @MrLister - Are we scraping the bottom (of the barrel)?

Comment: The question is unbecoming of the site IMHO - and I'm not convinced the actual answer is of any significance to you (or at all). So -1.

Comment: Prepare for a lot of pissed off fans.

Comment: I'm wondering, given the multi-species nature of TNG, if some of the crew have to go #3 (or even 4, 5, or 6?)

Comment: It seems the comments have stalled.

Comment: "Make it go, Number One."

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Where did he say that?

Comment: @iMerchant:   He didn't.   But "We need things...Things to make us go. "

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Based on a quick search of Chakoteya's excellent script search, at no point in Star Trek history has anyone uttered the words...

> [go number one/number two](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bline%7Cgo%20number,%7D))

...or any variation thereof. And while Picard has uttered the words...

> [have to go](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bspeaker%7Cpicard,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bline%7Chave%20to%20go,%7D))

...on no less than 13 separate occasions, none of them are in conjunction with Number One

---

That being said, you may be thinking of Q's rather funny quip in [TNG: True Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/True_Q_(episode)). At the time, Q was wearing a Starfleet Captain's uniform.

> [Riker ENTERS and stops when he sees Q and Amanda. Q is standing in
> front of her... her eyes are closed, as though concentrating on
> something. The minute Q sees Riker --]
>
> **Q:** *If it isn't Number Two...*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: True Q - Original Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/232.txt)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

or you might even be thinking of [Beavis and Butthead](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x18beia) (warning, NSFW content)

> **(Not)Picard:** *Number One, I order you to go take a number two.*
>
> **(Not)Riker:** *Aye Aye, Captain.*
>
> **(Not)Picard:** *Hehe. [Reflective Pause] This is cool*
>
> [image]

Comment: also, there was a Beavis and Butthead bit where they were dreaming they were on Star Trek. Jean-Butthead Pickard says "Number one, I order you to take a Number Two"

Comment: @KevinMilner - Worthy of its own edit.